# Weight Painting - using a single colour

Tags: weight-painting, customization

How exactly can you use a single colour when using Weight Paints? I've added a few in custom colours in the User Preferences - blue, light blue, green, orange and red - but no matter what brush type I use, I keep getting a mixture of two colours, eg: orange mixed with green, with the green around the sides of the orange. Is there any way of just using one solid colour?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of what you mean.
Weight painting needs at least two colors no matter what because it has to represent **values between 0 and 1**. So you will always have at least one color for 0, one color for 1 and it will display in between colors for every value between.

If you want to have only two colors for your weights paint (ie black and white), just set only two colors in your userprefs:

[image]

If you want to have as little transition as possible between values, use the "constant" interpolation and decay one of the sliders:

[image]