# Random vertices not following mesh during armature animation

Tags: animation, mesh, armature, weight-painting

First animation here. I've setup the armature and have an experimental walk animation going. But the certain vertices are not obeying the weights. What is even happening here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just from the animation it is hard to tell what the cause is. If you can, please upload the file to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/, edit the question and paste the generated link into your question.

Comment: Thanks @WhatAMesh for explaining how to do that. It's possible the mesh is too high-poly to weight reliably...

Comment: you simply need to correct that in Weight Paint mode

Comment: My first guess would be an issue with your weight paint. Often when working with weight paint something gets slightly painted and it's hard to catch. Try turning your colors to only black and white, it's much easier to see what you're working with. This might help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123369/weight-painting-using-a-single-colour